# How to control list of apps displayed at "Open In" at iOS

Tags: ios, uidocumentinteraction

As we know, at iOS, we could use UIDocumentInteractionController to display the "Open in" menu where a list of third party apps which could handle the document. User could pick one app to  open the document at that app.

We are looking for if we could only display a partial list at the "Open In" menu so we could apply security control here. With [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html), somehow we didn't find a way to do this. Is this possible at iOS?

Comment: I guess we could the approach at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283595/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-disable-open-in-certain-apps?rq=1 to block other apps to open the document by supplying a bad URL. however it could be quite frustrating to end  user since they don't know what apps are allowed and they would need to try to open at those apps to find out. The list of apps could be quite long, at least at my iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since no one is answering this question, I am going to answer myself. Based on current research, there is no way to do this at iOS 6. However at the iOS 7, there seems a new feature added to manage open in per these 2 links although I haven't got chance to look into API yet.

- http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2424581,00.asp  (open in management)
- http://www.maas360.com/products/mobile-device-management/apple-ios/  (Manage open in)